# suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integer such that $\phi(a)|\phi(b)$ then $a|b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

prove or disprove :

suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integer such that $\phi(a)|\phi(b)$ then $a|b$.

I see it false for example if $a=4$ and $b=3$ then $\phi(4)=2$ and φ(3)=2 so $\phi(a)|\phi(b)$ but $a\nmid b$.

is that right which I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

$\phi(4)=\phi(2^2)=2^2-2=2$ and $\phi(3)=3-1=2$ but $4\nmid 3$.

We can also let $a=3$ and $b=4$ as well.

A slightly "smaller" counter example is

$\phi(1)=1=\phi(2)$ but $2\nmid 1$.